# How to disconnect from receiver application?

Tags: java, android, google-cast

In my Chromecast Sender application, I have added a menu item to allow the user to stop the receiver app on the device (and made sure the "Disconnect" button in the Media Router Dialog *doesn't* stop the receiver, like it does in the CastHelloText-android sample app)

So, when the user taps the "Exit App" menu item, I am running the sample codes "teardown()" method (shown [here](https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloText-android/blob/master/src/com/example/casthelloworld/MainActivity.java#L347)). This code kills the reciever application, and should de-select the currently selected device.

However, whilst it does indeed kill the receiver app, it doesn't de-select the device, and the Cast icon stays in the selected state, and tapping it shows the dialog as if the phone was still connected to the Chromecast.

Obviously, if I then try to cast anything from my app, it can't.

So how do I fully disconnect from the device?

My teardown() method is 100% the same as in the linked code. Below is my menu code:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.exit_app:
            teardown();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call

```
mMediaRouter.selectRoute(mMediaRouter.getDefaultRoute())
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively

```
mMediaRouter.unselect(UNSELECT_REASON_DISCONNECTED)
```

Comment: Hi @Ali Naddaf,

I want to disconnect the app from Chromecast when user clear the app from stack. Is this possible?